# Prevent service overly window rotation after screen orientation change

Tags: java, android, android-service

Is this possible to prevent a service with overly window from rotating it's view when the device screen is rotated? Just like activities.

I'm aware that I can hard code each element fixing it's rotation according to the new orientation, but are there any more direct methods?

Answer (score 1):

Just add this following line in your Manifest. This will Prevent Screen Rotation.

```
<activity
        android:name=".YourService"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```